# Rails: Rendering a partial in a loop results in undefined variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble with attempting to render a partial within a loop. Essentially, I have an app where events are created, people join the event, and for each event, attendees have a list of items they will bring which they can select from their own inventory of items.

In my show.html.erb for Events:

```
           <% @event.attendees.each do |user| %>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <h4><%= user.first_name %> <%= user.last_name %></h4>

                <% if user.event_items.any?  %>

                <div class="event-item-list">
                  <% user.event_items.each do |eventitem| %>
                  <div class="event-item-div" >

                     <p class="event-item-title"><%= eventitem.item.title %></p>

                  </div>
                  <% end %>
                <% end %>
              </div>

                <% if user == current_user %>
                  <%= render 'event_items/form' %>
                <% end %>

             </div>
            <% end %>
```

This works and shows the title of each event item that is added to the list.

However, if I want to move the content of the P tag to a partial, I get "undefined local variable or method `eventitem'". Which doesn't make sense to me since I would assume that whatever is passed in as a partial in that loop would be treated the same as if I just left that P tag content in there. At this point, all I have in the partial would be:

```
<p class="event-item-title><%= eventitem.item.title %><p>
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to pass variable `eventitem` to the partial. It does not magically see local vars from parent partials/templates.

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#local-variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partials don't inherit local variables automagically, you have to define them. According to [Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables) to pass local variables to a partial you need to set them in the `locals` hash

```
<%= render 'event_items/form', locals: {eventitem: eventitem} %>
```